# What is the correct way to convert between a MySql bool and a C# bool?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm struggling to understand the correct way to **convert between a MySql bool and a C# bool**.

And it doesn't help that code which was working with **MySql.Data** v8.0.**21** no longer works with v8.0.**22**.

In the code below, why do I (now) need to specify the `MySqlDbType` as `Byte`? Surely `Bit` is a better presentation of a boolean value?

And why is the type of `cmd.Parameters["success"].Value` either `ulong` or `sbyte`? Shouldn't it be `bool`?

```
[TestFixture]
public class MySqlTests
{
    private const string connString = "server=localhost;database=mysql;user=root;password=";

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        using var cnn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        cnn.Open();
        var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"
            DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Test;
            CREATE PROCEDURE Test (OUT success BOOL)
            BEGIN
                SET success = true;
            END
        ";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    [TestCase(MySqlDbType.Bit, typeof(ulong))] // succeeds with MySql.Data v8.0.21, fails with v8.0.22
    [TestCase(MySqlDbType.Byte, typeof(sbyte))]
    public void Test(MySqlDbType mySqlDbType, Type expectedType)
    {
        using var cnn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        cnn.Open();
        var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Test";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("success", mySqlDbType) {Direction = ParameterDirection.Output});
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var success = cmd.Parameters["success"].Value;
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedType, success.GetType(), "Unexpected Type");
    }
}
```

If it matters, I'm running MySql:5.7

Comment: This appears to be a regression in 8.0.22. It _might_ be related to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101253, or it could be completely different. You could file a bug at bugs.mysql.com and wait for Oracle to address it, but my recommendation would be to switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ (disclaimer: lead author) as it's far more stable, performant, and fixes a lot of MySql.Data issues: https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs

Comment: I would file a bug...but I'd have to create an Oracle account. Going to swap over to using your MySqlConnector package +1

Comment: I opened a bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101302

Comment: I've the same problem, thanks for the bug report. Seems that it's fixed in 8.0.23, but it's not released for the time of this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql does not have a real boolean data type, bool is just an [alias of tinyint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/other-vendor-data-types.html). Tinyint is [stored on 1 byte](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html), so it maps to C#'s sbyte data type.

Why different versions of mysql data handle this mapping differently, I cannot tell, you need to ask the developers.

Comment: Tinyint data type is signed by default, so that was a typo from me.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't nitpicking...just surprised that they've chosen to use a non-CLS-compliant type.

Comment: Mysql is accessible through a number of programming languages, not just through .Net. Mysql cannot possibly be expected to comply with the data types of all of them.

Comment: Sure, but the Mysql.Data library should provide a. Net idiomatic API

Comment: Mapping boolean to byte data type would mean the driver has to convert the data between the client and the server. Not sure if that's the right approach if there is a data type that maps directly to the data type used in mysql.